# Android tv app is crashing while playing video

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-videoview, android-tv, android-7.1-nougat

I have built a carousel app for android tv, which shows images and plays videos. But recently it started crashing once the video starts playing. I have tested this on a mobile device it's working fine working fine.
Errors I got - 
`E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147479552)`
`E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)`
`E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147479552)`
`E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-38)`
`E/MediaPlayer: stop called in state 0, mPlayer(0xd317c860)`
`E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)`

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mkaB.png

Test Device Info :

- X96mini media box
- Android Version 7.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once video playback completed, call stopPlayback() method. it's working fine now.

```
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(mp -> { videoView.stopPlayback();} )
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you invoke stop() API as soon as created the player instance?
If you update the SDK and it was called the stop in a idle state of player then it would be got the error.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#Valid_and_Invalid_States